# Python data slice, the new output value will overwrite the previous value

Tags: python, pandas, csv, slice, chunks

I have a huge csv file and I need to classify it, so I chose to read in blocks. The code runs very well, but the new output value will overwrite the previous value.
When the code processes the second block, the output value will overwrite the value of the first block

my code：

```py
import pandas as pd

def result(data):
      List= 'location_country' 
      a1 = 'united states'
      q1 = data[(data[List] == a1)]
      q1.to_csv('G:\\1\\'+a1+'.csv', 'a',sep=',',   index=False)
table = pd.read_csv('G:\\gz\\4.csv', sep=',',chunksize=1000000)
for df in table:
 result(df)
```

Comment: Make sure to include mode='a'.

Comment: nice~ The problem is solved, but the header will be written repeatedly.

Comment: Include header=None